# How to turn off :hover after user clicks button?

Tags: javascript, css

I need my `:hover` effect to stop and revert to the non-hover mode after the button is clicked.

style.css

```
my-login-button: {
  color: white;
}
my-login-button:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

When user clicks `my-login-button`, the user gets logged in. When they logout, the login button is still blue until they hover over it again and `mouseout`.

How do I get the login button automatically white when the user logs out?

Comment: With classes? You might want to show a little bit more of your code.

Answer (score 2):

change your css to not apply to clicked buttons like this

```
.my-login-button {
  color: white;
}
.my-login-button:not(.clicked):hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

on click add class clicked

```
$('.my-login-button').on('click', function() {
$(this).addClass('clicked')
})
```

Comment: Didn't even know you could use ´not´ like that. Cool thanks.

Comment: I'm the OP. I +1 your answer because it helps. I am in the process of evaluating and testing all the answers in order to select and accept an answer. So far, yours seems promising. The issue I'm having is... you interpreted `my-login-button` as a class. It's not. It's actually a custom element. But that's a minor issue assuming I can use the same syntax. The real issue is that it looks like I will have to remove the `.clicked` class the next time the user loads the page (if I want `:hover` to work properly). Which puts me back where I started. Is that correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: when user loads(hard loading) the page all classes added with javascript will be reseted as well

Comment: I know. But when they log out, my page is not hard reloaded. So that's a sticking point. I have to do some further research into the code to see if there is a logout event or something I can hook to.

Comment: yes, i guess you need to handle some code on logout too

Comment: Thing is, it's cleaner to do it at login time. Because then I have the event data as there are multiple login buttons. I didn't want to confuse the question with too much detail. But that is one of the details I left out for simplicity.

Comment: @Mowzer If it's just about toggling class, use .toggleClass

Comment: if you give a specific JSFiddle displaying the problem i will try to help as much as i can

Answer (score 1):

On click of my-login-button remove class my-login-button:hover and add class my-login-button.

```
$('#Button').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var btn = document.getElementById("my-login-button"); 
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        btn.style.color="white";
    }
```